# How to unwrap deep list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I get a nested list as input.
Simplified version is as under.

```
myList=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]
```

I wish to unpack it into a simple list of lists.
I can do like this--

```
    simpleList=[]
    for i in myList:
        for j in i:
            simpleList.append(j)
```

As desired, the simpleList is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 7], [5, 7, 9]]
```

**My question:-**
What I did was, maybe, a beginner's coding approach.
Is there a more professional, efficient (and *pythonic*) approach to unpack this nested list?
Thanks.

**EDIT**:-
My method doesn't work for deeply nested lists.
e.g.  `[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]]`
pl. refer to the comments to answers.

Comment: `sum(myList, [])`, but `itertools.chain` based solution will be more efficient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `recursive` function in order to **solve nested list with any depth**.

```
def unwrap_list(mylist, result):
   if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in mylist):
      for value in mylist:
         unwrap_list(value, result)
   else:
      result.append(mylist)

mylist = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]
result = []
unwrap_list(mylist, result)
print(result)
```

Another approach is using a **generator**.

```
def flatten(L):
    for item in L:
        if any(isinstance(i, list) for i in item):
          yield from flatten(item)
        else:
          yield item
```

Comment: yes, this can solve the task. But as the python idiom says -- "simple is better than complex", lambda or chain approach can do this in one liner. Maybe, there is any performance benefit by your suggested solution. Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet, there is no performance benefit, but it seems that for following example other answers don't work: `[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]]`

Comment: Great @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut . Your method addresses the question most appropriately. I have accepted this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, the lambda or chain approaches can be modified in a way it solves the problem. Can you pl. share your knowledge on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet, I tried answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python , but it seems that you have to use recursion to lists with any depth.

Comment: I too tried some answers from that thread, but with erroneous result. I better stick to recursion for deeply nested lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `chain` from **itertools**

```
from itertools import chain
myList=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]
print(list(chain.from_iterable(myList)))   #print(list(chain(*myList)))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 7], [5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: better `print(list(chain.from_iterable(myList)))`

Comment: @Vineet, you can also use a native recursive method like in my answer.

Comment: @Rakesh, it seems that this answer don't work with `[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
myList=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, myList)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 7], [5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: As @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut rightly pointed out, this solution doesn't work with [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[4,6,7],[5,7,9]]]]